# Why does $\mathbb C_p$ not contain the periods?

Tags: cohomology, rigid-analytic-geometry, p-adic-hodge-theory, non-archimedean-fields, periods

I am reading the following article of [Berger, p8](https://mat.uab.cat/%7Emasdeu/files/padichodge/berger_intro_theory_padic_reps.pdf) and I don't understand the idea:

> $C_p:=\widehat{\overline{\mathbb Q_p}}$ does not contain the periods

The text seem to reason as follows

> (under some conditions)
> $$ H^0(K, C_p(\chi^{-1})) = \{x \in C_p \, : \, gx = \chi(\sigma)x \forall \sigma \in G_K\} =0  $$
> for some character $\chi:G_K \rightarrow  \mathbb Z_p^\times$, where this set is the "set of periods".

Question:

- How does this relate to the classical of notion of periods/why is this set periods?

Details / explanations would be appreciated!

---

My thoughts: (Can ignore)

What I know: one formualtion of periods in the $\mathbb Q/\mathbb C$ setting is that that they are coefficients in the comparison iso.
$$ C_{dR}: H^n_{dR}(X(\mathbb C), \mathbb Q) \otimes \mathbb C \simeq H^n_{Betti}(X(\mathbb C), \mathbb Q) \otimes_{\mathbb Q} \mathbb C $$
I believe our example here is consider $\mathbb G_{m,\mathbb Q_p}$.

What I don't see: how Galois groups even come into play.

---

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider the Tate motive $\mathbb Q(1)$. Its de Rham realization is simply $\mathbb Q$ (with the filtration $F^{-1}\mathbb Q=\mathbb Q$ and $F^{0}=0$) and its Betti realization is $2\pi i\mathbb Q$. The comparison theorem you recalled works because after extension of scalars to $\mathbb C$, you can multiply by $2\pi i$.

However, the observation of Tate recalled by Laurent Berger that you mentioned above tells you that $\mathbb C_{p}(1)=\{0\}$. Thus $\mathbb C_{p}(1)$, which is the étale realization of $\mathbb Q(1)$ after extension of scalars to $\mathbb C_{p}$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb C_{p}$, which is the de Rham realization of $\mathbb Q(1)$ after extension of scalars to $\mathbb C_{p}$. You would encounter similar problems if you were to believe that the period ring for the Betti-de Rham comparison isomorphism is $\mathbb R$ (in that case there would be no compatibility in the filtration and Hodge structure)

So one needs to extend to a ring which contains something like $2\pi i$ in the $p$-adic world, and that is the ring $B_{{dR}}$ of Jean-Marc Fontaine.